# IE10 - file input: TIFF files and accept attribute

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

```
<input type="file" accept="image/tiff" />
```

If we have a TIFF file with the `.tif` extension not `.tiff` this file won't be shown if we defined `accept` attribute as `image/tiff`. In case we set it to `.tif` all will work just fine.

Can anybody explain why MIME type `image/tiff` doesn't work with files with `.tif` extension (IE10)?

- image/tiff - http://jsfiddle.net/eK3Dz/
- .tif - http://jsfiddle.net/eK3Dz/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably because `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MIME\Database\Content Type\image/tiff` defines the Extension as `.tiff` and there's no easy way for IE to know that `.tif` is also a valid extension.

This limitation should probably be filed on Microsoft Connect's IE page.

You could do something like: `<input type="file" accept="image/tiff,.tif">`